# How can I fix the ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE  
    p_id number;  
    p_email varchar2(500); 
    p_amount number; 
    p_fees number;
    p_reference varchar2(500);
BEGIN
 SELECT
    id,
    email, 
    amount, 
    fees,
    pr_reference

  INTO
    p_id,
    p_email, 
    p_amount, 
    p_fees,
    p_reference
         FROM paygate_payload p,  JSON_TABLE(
         p.payload,'$'
         COLUMNS (
             email varchar2(500) path '$.details.customer_email',
             amount varchar2(500) path '$.details.data.amount',
             fees varchar2(500) path '$.details.data.chargeamount',
             pr_reference varchar2(500) path '$.details.data.paymentreference'
       )
         ) 
         where status = 'draft';
         update paygate_payload set status = 'done' where id = p_id;
         begin
       pgt_app.register_paygate_event(p_email, p_amount, p_fees, p_reference);
       end;
end;
```

I get the error below when I run the above code

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 8
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1766
6.     p_reference varchar2(500);
7. BEGIN
8.  SELECT
9.     id,
10.     email,

Comment: well, your query is returning more than one row.  So either the query needs to be narrowed , or you need to use a cursor and iterate through the results.

Comment: Most likely, your JSON data has 2 or more entries for one of those fields. Please edit your question to add example JSON data which causes this error, and what you want to do about it.